libgdx: ExtendViewport -> Tiled images no longer fit after changing the screen resolution
Scene2D
My game works fine with Fit and FillViewport.
If I set to ExtendViewport, the coordinates of the tilemap are no longer correct after changing the screen resolution.
The actor will then be displayed much higher.
If the actor is at the bottom of the screen, it will be rendered too high up.
If the actor is at the top of the screen, it will be rendered too far down.
Where is the mistake?
[enter image desfirstcription here]3
ur.com/zrPAx.png
    enter code herepublic class TilemapActor extends Actor
{
// window dimensions
public static int windowWidth  = 1920;
public static int windowHeight = 1080;

private TiledMap tiledMap;
private OrthographicCamera tiledCamera;
private OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;

/**
 *  Initialize Tilemap created with the Tiled Map Editor.
 */
public TilemapActor(String filename, Stage theStage)
{
    // set up tile map, renderer, and camera
    //tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load(filename);

//        tiledMap=RamManager.manager.get(filename);
tiledMap=RamManager.manager.get(filename);
    int tileWidth          = (int)tiledMap.getProperties().get("tilewidth");
    int tileHeight         = (int)tiledMap.getProperties().get("tileheight");
    int numTilesHorizontal = (int)tiledMap.getProperties().get("width");
    int numTilesVertical   = (int)tiledMap.getProperties().get("height");
    int mapWidth  = tileWidth  * numTilesHorizontal;
    int mapHeight = tileHeight * numTilesVertical;

    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthoCachedTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
    tiledMapRenderer.setBlending(true);
    tiledCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
    tiledCamera.setToOrtho(false, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    tiledCamera.update();

    // by adding object to Stage, can be drawn automatically
    theStage.addActor(this);

    // in theory, a solid boundary should be placed around the edge of the screen,
    //  but just in case, this map can be used to set boundaries
    BaseActor.setWorldBounds(mapWidth, mapHeight);
}

/**
 *  Search the map layers for Rectangle Objects that contain a property (key) called         `enter code here`"name" with associated value propertyName.
 *  Typically used to store non-actor information such as SpawnPoint locations or dimensions of Solid objects.
 *  Retrieve data as object, then cast to desired type: for example, float w = (float)obj.getProperties().get("width").
 */
public ArrayList<MapObject> getRectangleList(String propertyName)
{
    ArrayList<MapObject> list = new ArrayList<MapObject>();

    for ( MapLayer layer : tiledMap.getLayers() )
    {
        for ( MapObject obj : layer.getObjects() )
        {
            if ( !(obj instanceof RectangleMapObject) )
                continue;

            MapProperties props = obj.getProperties();

            if ( props.containsKey("name") && props.get("name").equals(propertyName) )
                list.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

/**
 *  Search the map layers for Tile Objects (tile-like elements of object layers)
 *  that contain a property (key) called "name" with associated value propertyName.
 *  Typically used to store actor information and will be used to create instances.
 */
public ArrayList<MapObject> getTileList(String propertyName)
{
    ArrayList<MapObject> list = new ArrayList<MapObject>();

    for ( MapLayer layer : tiledMap.getLayers() )
    {
        for ( MapObject obj : layer.getObjects() )
        {
            if ( !(obj instanceof TiledMapTileMapObject) )
                continue;

            MapProperties props = obj.getProperties();

            // Default MapProperties are stored within associated Tile object
            // Instance-specific overrides are stored in MapObject

            TiledMapTileMapObject tmtmo = (TiledMapTileMapObject)obj;
            TiledMapTile t = tmtmo.getTile();
            MapProperties defaultProps = t.getProperties();

            if ( defaultProps.containsKey("name") && defaultProps.get("name").equals(propertyName) )
                list.add(obj);

            // get list of default property keys
            Iterator<String> propertyKeys = defaultProps.getKeys();

            // iterate over keys; copy default values into props if needed
            while ( propertyKeys.hasNext() )
            {
                String key = propertyKeys.next();

                // check if value already exists; if not, create property with default value
                if ( props.containsKey(key) )
                    continue;
                else
                {
                    Object value = defaultProps.get(key);
                    props.put( key, value );
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public void act(float dt)
{
    super.act( dt );
}

public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha)
{
    // adjust tilemap camera to stay in sync with main camera
    Camera mainCamera = getStage().getCamera();
    tiledCamera.position.x = mainCamera.position.x;
    tiledCamera.position.y = mainCamera.position.y;
    tiledCamera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(tiledCamera);

    // need the following code to force batch order,
    //  otherwise it is batched and rendered last
    batch.end();
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
    batch.begin();
}

}
public BaseScreen()
{
    mainStage = new Stage(viewport = new ExtendViewport(1920, 1080));
    uiStage = new Stage(viewport = new ExtendViewport(1920, 1080));

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    assMan.loadAll();

//        assMan.manager.finishLoading();//Wird in splash Screen aufgerufen für Ladeanzeige (Balken)
    initialize();
}

public abstract void initialize();

public abstract void update(float dt);

public void render(float dt)
{

//        assMan.manager.update();
    // act methods
    uiStage.act(dt);
    mainStage.act(dt);

    // clear the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw the graphics
    mainStage.draw();
    uiStage.draw();

    // defined by user
    update(dt);

}

// methods required by Screen interface
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    mainStage.getViewport().update(width, height);
    uiStage.getViewport().update(width, height);

}


u may Replace ExtendViewport with ScreenViewport
